# Specifying table dependency when many entries in upstream table for one entry in downstream table

Tags: datajoint

I would like to create a datajoint computed table that depends on multiple entries (about 20) from an upstream table. I know it is possible to create a table that depends on multiple entries from an upstream table using the .proj method to rename a primary key, but I do not think this would work in my case since datajoint caps the number of allowed primary keys around 16. Is there any way to specify a formal dependency between an upstream table and downstream table when doing so would require having more than the allowed number of primary keys in the downstream table? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key in the child table always refers to one entry in the parent table. If the child entry always refers to exactly two entries in the parent, then you can have a pair of foreign keys, renaming the foreign key attribute. If you must refer to an arbitrary subset, then you will need to model an additional master-part relationship.

Let me illustrate with a neuroscience example in Python. Imagine you are recording from cells in a brain slice. Let's model that:

```py
import datajoint as dj

schema = dj.Schema('multipatch_study')

@schema
class Slice(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    slice : int 
    ---
    slice_description : varchar(1000)
    """
    
    
@schema
class Cell(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    -> Slice
    cell : int 
    """
```

Now imagine we perform a paired recording where we stimulate one cell and record from another. This recording depends on exactly two cells and the dependency is ordered: there is Cell #1 and Cell #2. In this case, we can have two separate foreign keys.

```py
@schema
class PairedRecording(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    -> Cell.proj(presynaptic = 'cell')
    -> Cell.proj(postsynaptic = 'cell')
    """
```

But imagine now that you patched multiple cells simultaneously and record from them. Let's call this group of simultaneously patched cells a 'cohort' and define it as a master-part relationship.

```py
@schema
class Cohort(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    -> Slice
    cohort : int
    """

    class Cell(dj.Part):
        definition = """
        -> master
        -> Cell
        """
```

The master-part relationship `Cohort`/`Cohort.Cell` implies that any Cohort is always created and destroyed as a single transaction with all its cells. Cells cannot be added to or removed from an existing cohort. A dependency on `Cohort` is equivalent to a dependency on the entire group of cells it represents.

When you design the next step in the analysis importing the recording, you can just point to `Cohort`.

```py
@schema 
class Multipatch(dj.Imported):
    definition = """
    -> Cohort
    ---
    current_clamp : longblob  # (mV) (channels x time) 
    """
```

Then the connectivity analysis can refer to the multipatch recording:

```py
@schema 
class Connectivity(dj.Computed):
    definition = """
    -> Multipatch
    ---
    connectivity : longblob  # connectivity matrix (channels x channels) 
    """
```

The resulting dependency diagram is as follows:
[image: Dependency Diagram]

#### Mapping channels

As a bonus, let's modify the `Cohort` table to also specify the recording channels for each cell in the cohort. The channel number must be unique within the cohort, so we must add a unique index.

```py
@schema
class Cohort(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    -> Slice
    cohort : int
    """

    class Cell(dj.Part):
        definition = """
        -> master
        -> Cell
        ---
        channel : int
        unique index (slice, cohort, channel)
        """
```

Happy DataJointing!

Comment: This is very helpful; thanks!